# configure hibernate to map entities automaticly

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations

I use hibernate ORM in my project. 
Now I map entities like this :

```
<mapping class="entities.User"/>
```

but I have to do this for each entity I create - is there anything I can put in the hibernate configuration to make it scan itself for annotated entities in certain package?

thank you

Comment: You have an alternative `cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Entity.class)` but I don't think that mapping can be automated.

Answer (score 1):

You can place all your java entities in a `JAR` file and then provide the path of the `JAR` file in hibernate configuration file like this:

```
<mapping jar="path_to_your_jar_file"/>
```

**Update:**

This is helpful only if you have hbm.xml files for mapping instead of having annotations on your classes. These mapping files should be part of the JAR file.

Look at this link for [addJar](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addJar%28java.io.File%29) method of `Configuration` class.

Answer (score 1):

Using spring can help you get the package scanned. See the config below

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.tds.hibernate.entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```